# Remove Dashes from Row 2 on file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a bat file that uses SQLCMD to call an SQL Statement

My SQL statement is fine

However, under the header row, in Row 2, I get a load of dashes like so,

```
SKU,Name,Description
---,----,-----------
123,Apple,Fruit
124,Orange,Fruit
125,Broccoli,Veg
12-9,Grapes,Fruit
13-7,Kiwi,Fruit
```

Example Code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD" -S TEST-SQL02 -E -Q "SET nocount ON; select * from fruitveg;" -s "," -W -o "E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt"
```

Should look like:

```
SKU,Name,Description
123,Apple,Fruit
124,Orange,Fruit
125,Broccoli,Veg
12-9,Grapes,Fruit
13-7,Kiwi,Fruit
```

I have tried including -h-1 and -h -1 but removes header and dashes

Also, I have tried writing PS script to remove the dashes

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt" | ForEach-Object {Set-Content (Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1) -Path $_}
```

but removes header and dashes

I need to keep dashes in SKUS whenever the occur

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74707382/edit) try to format your question better. Formatting examples as code usually helps. You can highlight the text and press the `{}` button on the text editor, or press Ctrl+K on your keyboard to format things as code.

Comment: Is that output **exactly** how you show it? Do you indeed have all those comma's in between or are we actually looking at the normal PowerShell console output where there is a dash line underneath the headers, but there should be no commas then

Comment: You might try this [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet.

Comment: @Theo, the dashed field record is common for the SQLCmd output, it has nothing to do with the type of output returned from many PowerShell commands.

Comment: @Compo Thanks, I didn't know that. Because of the dot in `Apple.` it seemed to me that the post was hand-typed adding extra commas too. I've just posted an answer showing how to clean up the file when it is written like that.

Comment: Being new to the platform, may I ask you to see the [tour], where amongst other interesting things, you can read how to mark a question 'done' if one of the given answers solves your problem. This will also be of benefit to other users that may have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what the `sqlcmd` switches do, but presuming that omitting `-o "E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt"` will deliver the report to the console, then

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD" -S TEST-SQL02 -E -Q "SET nocount ON; select * from fruitveg;" -s "," -W |findstr /v /b "-">"E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt"

should remove that troublesome line.

findstr: Find all lines that `/v` do NOT `/b` begin with "-" but the `-` needs to be escaped.

Comment: I only need hypens removed from the 2nd row. I need hypens if they occur in skus

Comment: You have leading hyphens on SKUs?

Comment: Not at start of sku

Comment: The `findstr` command only detects `-` at the start of the line (`/b` means "line begins")

Comment: I am getting FINDSTR: Bad Command Line when I run this code

Comment: Need a backslash before the dash. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise that you just pipe the StdOut from SQLCmd.exe directly to FindStr.exe, matching all lines which contain any character which is not a dash or a comma.

```bash
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.exe" -S "TEST-SQL02" -E -Q "SET nocount ON; SELECT * FROM fruitveg;" -s "," -W 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "[^\-,]" 1>"E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt"
```

This methodology is more robust than assuming that no wanted line begins with one, (or more), dashes, and excluding those from the results.

Comment: I am getting FINDSTR: Bad Command Line when I run this code

Comment: Paddy, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the `findstr.exe` portion of my above code example. To prove it, why not create the file content shown in your question, name it `test.txt`, then in a Command Prompt window, (with the current directory that which holds your `test.txt`), type ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "[^\-,]" "test.txt"```, and press `[ENTER]`. You should not see that message at all, which indicates the issue is not a bad `findstr.exe` command.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

If what you show us in the post on screen actually looks like this:

```
SKU Name     Description
--- ----     -----------
123 Apple.   Fruit      
124 Orange   Fruit      
125 Broccoli Veg
```

so, without those commas, then this is the default Format-Table output for an array of objects in PowerShell.

If however that is the output of your SQL statement , then with PowerShell you can clean-up the file using

```
(Get-Content -Path "E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt" -Raw) -replace '(?m)^[-,]+\r?\n' | 
Set-Content -Path "E:\Paddy\Test\test.txt"
```

This will remove the dashed line leaving you with a workable CSV file.

P.S. why is there a dot after `Apple` ?

Comment: I suppose the period suffix to Apple is for the same reason as the space prefix on both Broccoli and Veg, and likely irrelevant.

Comment: @Compo Yeah, you're probably right. It just made me wonder..

Comment: Typo. This was just example that i typed out.  The table i am pulling from is much larger as is the ouput.  Did this example for simplicity.